# UIWebView Resize CGRektMake

Tags: ios, uiwebview, resize, cgrectmake

A few weeks ago i started a "xcode" project in which i had to resize a `UIWebView`. I did this with

```
webView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 118, 320, 410);
```

It worked perfectly, no issues.

Then, yesterday i started a new project and i wanted to do the same thing, so i tried with the exact same code. But it didn't work.

```
webView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 100.0);
```

and

```
[self.webView setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 100.0)];
```

Nothing worked.
Then i returned the values of the `webView` frame before and after resizing.

> Function called
>   25.000000
>   77.000000
>   282.000000
>   183.000000
>   Value changed
>   0.000000
>   0.000000
>   100.000000
>   100.000000

So it looks like it resizes the `webView`, but i the app itself it does nothing. what am i doing wrong? i bet its just one little thing but i really need some help

Thanks. ;)

Comment: set delegate to webview

Comment: Webview.delegate=self;

Comment: i did that, in both projects, didn't work

Comment: try this :self.webView.frame = CGRectMake(self.webView.frame.origin.x, self.webView.frame.origin.y, self.webView.frame.size.width, 0);
  [self.webView reload];

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WebView in .xib then check that *IBOutlet* is set properly.